# Populate TableView with data from CSV file

Tags: csv, javafx, tableview

This application will write and read to a csv file with the aid of the Person class.It will NOT populate the table with data. I am trying to execute the loading of the table at the same time the csv file is loaded to the list = new ArrayList()by loading the same data to plist = new ArrayList() then transferring this plist to the data=FXCollections.observableList(plist)

Please explain where this code is failing. Is it not possible to load the observableList
at the same time the list ArrayList is loaded or is the transfer from list to plist not working?
I am also not sure the CellValueFactory is invoked. Suggested fix would be appreciated.
I do not want to use 3rd Party API and would not desire to use the TableView to add/delete data.

```
MainClass
package appCSVFile;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class CSVMain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage pStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("csv.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,1040,650);
            pStage.setScene(scene);
            pStage.setResizable(false);
            pStage.setTitle("CSV File Demo");
            pStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
Controller Class
package appCSVFile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Scanner;


import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

public class CSVController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private AnchorPane apCSV;
    @FXML private Pane paneONE;

    @FXML public TextField txfFName;
    @FXML public TextField txfLName;
    @FXML public TextField txfPNum;
    @FXML public TextField txfEMail;
    @FXML private VBox vbxDir;

    @FXML public TableView<Person> table;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Person, String> tblColFName;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Person, String> tblColLName;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Person, String> tblColPNum;
    @FXML public TableColumn<Person, String> tblColEMail;

    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    public ArrayList<Contacts> list;
    private ListIterator<Contacts> LIT;
    private int i;

    public ArrayList<Person> plist;
    public ObservableList<Person> data;

    @FXML
    private void onDir(ActionEvent e) {
        vbxDir.setVisible(true);
        vbxDir.toFront();
    }
    @FXML
    private void onClose(ActionEvent e) {
        vbxDir.setVisible(false);
    }

    @FXML//Load CSV Data
    private void onLoad(ActionEvent e)throws IOException {

        File fileInfo = new File("C:/A_CSV/People.csv");
        if(fileInfo.length()==0) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            alert.setHeaderText("");
            alert.setContentText("No Data in File at "+ fileInfo+"\n"+
            "Enter Data and Save");
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;  
        }

        fc.setTitle("Load Contacts Info");
        fc.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:/"));
        fc.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:/A_CSV"));
        fc.setInitialFileName("People.csv");
        File file = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (file == null) {
        return;
        }

        String correctFile = file.getName();
        if(!(correctFile.matches("People.csv"))){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            alert.setHeaderText("");
            alert.setContentText("The File at " + file + "\n\n"+
            "is NOT accociated with this application\n\n"+
            "Select the File at "+fileInfo);
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }

        Path dirP = Paths.get(String.valueOf(file));
        InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(dirP);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        list = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
        plist = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader);
        scan.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");

        while (scan.hasNext()){
           String fname = scan.next();
           String lname = scan.next();
           String pnum = scan.next();
           String email = scan.next();

           txfFName.setText(String.valueOf(fname));
           txfLName.setText(String.valueOf(lname));
           txfPNum.setText(String.valueOf(pnum));
           txfEMail.setText(String.valueOf(email));


           list.add(new Contacts(fname,lname,pnum,email));

           plist.add(new Person(fname,lname,pnum,email));
           data = FXCollections.observableList(plist);

           table = new TableView<>();
           table.setItems(data);

        TableColumn<Person,String> tblColFName = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        tblColFName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("vfname"));
        tblColFName.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tblColFName.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {

                t.getTableView().getItems()
                    .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    .setFName(t.getNewValue());
            }

        });

        TableColumn<Person,String> tblColLName = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        tblColLName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("vlname"));
        tblColLName.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tblColLName.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {

                t.getTableView().getItems()
                    .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    .setLName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });

        TableColumn<Person,String> tblColPNum = new TableColumn<>("Phone Number");
        tblColPNum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("vpnum"));
        tblColPNum.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tblColPNum.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {

                t.getTableView().getItems()
                    .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    .setPNum(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });

        TableColumn<Person,String> tblColEMail = new TableColumn<>("Email Address");
        tblColEMail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("vemail"));
        tblColEMail.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tblColEMail.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {

                t.getTableView().getItems()
                    .get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    .setEMail(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });

//System.out.println(list.size());//2
//System.out.println(plist.containsAll(data));//true
//System.out.println(plist.size());//2

       }
       scan.close();

        LIT = list.listIterator();                  
        if (LIT.hasNext()){          
            Contacts p = LIT.next();
            getContacts(p); 
        } 
    }

    @FXML//This code removes data from the ArrayList and RE-Writes to the
     //People.csv file the file is deleted first then rewritten
    private void onRemove(ActionEvent e)throws IOException{

    if(txfFName.getText().isEmpty()||txfLName.getText().isEmpty()||txfPNum.getText().isEmpty()||txfEMail.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("No Data Present to REMOVE\n"+
        "Click LOAD to Obtain Data");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return; 
    }

    list.get(i);
    list.remove(i);

    if(0 == list.size()){
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:/A_CSV", "People.csv");
    Files.delete(path);
        onClear(e);
        list.clear();
    return;
    }else if(i == list.size()){     
        i = i - 1;
    }
    Contacts p = list.get(i);
        getContacts(p);
        Contacts dat;

        for(int r = 0; r <list.size(); r++){
        dat = list.get(r);  
        }  
       Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:/A_CSV", "People.csv");
       Files.delete(path);

       File file = new File("C:/A_CSV/People.csv");
            if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.getPath(),true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);  
        Iterator<Contacts> LIT = list.iterator();
            while(LIT.hasNext()) {
                dat = LIT.next();
                String d = dat.toString();
                bufferWritter.write(d);
        }

        bufferWritter.close();
        onClear(e);
        //list.clear();//this is done by onClear(e)
        txfFName.requestFocus();
    }

    @FXML//Scroll forward through the ArrayList
    private void onNext(ActionEvent e) {

        if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("Load Data First");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return;
        }

        if (i == list.size()- 1) {
        i = 0;
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("Last Record in File");
        alert.showAndWait();
        i= list.size()-1;
        return;
        }else {
        i = i + 1;
        }
            Contacts p = list.get(i);
            getContacts(p); 
    }

    @FXML//Scroll backwards through the ArrayList
    private void onPrevious(ActionEvent e) {

        if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("Load Data First");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return;
        }

        if (i == 0) {
        i = list.size()-1;
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("First Record in File");
        alert.showAndWait();
        i=0;
        return;
        }else {
        i = i - 1 ;
        }
            Contacts p = list.get(i); 
            getContacts(p);
    }

    //Helper for Contacts Class
    private void getContacts(Contacts p){
        txfFName.setText("" + p.getFName());
        txfLName.setText("" + p.getLName());
        txfPNum.setText ("" + p.getPnum());
        txfEMail.setText("" + p.getEmail());    
    }

    @FXML
    private void oneSave(ActionEvent e) throws IOException{

    if(txfFName.getText().isEmpty() || txfLName.getText().isEmpty() || txfPNum.getText().isEmpty() || txfEMail.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("No DATA entered\n"+
        "ENTER new data and Alt + S to SAVE");
        alert.showAndWait();

        if(txfFName.getText().isEmpty()) {
            txfFName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(txfLName.getText().isEmpty()) {
            txfLName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(txfPNum.getText().isEmpty()) {
            txfPNum.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(txfEMail.getText().isEmpty()) {
            txfEMail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }   
    }

    String fname = txfFName.getText().trim();
    String lname = txfLName.getText().trim();
    String pnum = txfPNum.getText().trim();
    String email = txfEMail.getText().trim();
    String data = (fname + "," + lname + "," + pnum + "," + email + "," + '\r');

    File dirPath = new File("C:/A_CSV");
    dirPath.mkdirs();//Make the directory

    File file = new File(dirPath,"People.csv");
    if(!file.exists()){
       file.createNewFile();//Create and empty text file
    }

    Alert alert1 = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert1.setTitle("Confirm Save");
    alert1.setHeaderText("");
    alert1.setContentText("Select OK to Save Data");
    //Alert Do You Want to SAVE
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert1.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.getPath(),true);
        try (BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)) {
            bufferWritter.write(data);

        //Alert that you did SAVE too many Alerts!          
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Data Saved");
        alert.showAndWait();
        txfFName.setText("");
        txfLName.setText("");
        txfPNum.setText("");
        txfEMail.setText("");
        txfFName.requestFocus();
    }

    } else {
        return;
        //if you did not save do we clear the entered data ?
        // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
    }
    }

    @FXML//Clear Fields and ArrayList
    private void onClear(ActionEvent e) {

    if(txfFName.getText().isEmpty()||txfLName.getText().isEmpty()||txfPNum.getText().isEmpty()||txfEMail.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("No Data Present to CLEAR\n"+
        "Click LOAD to Obtain Data");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return; 
    }
    i=0;
    list.clear();
    txfFName.setText("");
    txfLName.setText("");
    txfPNum.setText("");
    txfEMail.setText("");
    txfFName.requestFocus();
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        //table.setPlaceholder(new Label("No visible columns and/or data exist."));
    }

    }
Contacts Class
package appCSVFile;

public class Contacts {

    private String FName;
    private String LName;
    private String PNum;
    private String EMail;

    //public Contacts(String pFname, String pLname, String pPnum, String pEmail) {
        //super();
        //this.FName = pFname;
        //this.LName = pLname;
        //this.PNum  = pPnum;
        //this.EMail = pEmail;
    //}
    public Contacts(String pFname,String pLname, String pPnum, String pEmail){
        FName = pFname;
        LName = pLname;
        PNum =  pPnum;
        EMail = pEmail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return FName + "," + 
           LName + "," +
           PNum  + "," +
           EMail + "," + '\r' ;
}
    public String toFile(){
        return FName + "," + LName + "," + PNum + "," + EMail + "," +'\r';
    }
    public String getFName(){
        return FName;
    }
    public String getLName(){
        return LName;
    }
    public String getPnum(){
        return PNum;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return EMail;
    }
}

Person Class
package appCSVFile;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person  {

    private SimpleStringProperty vfname;
    private SimpleStringProperty vlname;
    private SimpleStringProperty vpnum;
    private SimpleStringProperty vemail;

    public Person () {
    }

    public Person (String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {

        vfname = new SimpleStringProperty(s1);
        vlname = new SimpleStringProperty(s2);
        vpnum  = new SimpleStringProperty(s3);
        vemail = new SimpleStringProperty(s4);
        //System.out.println(s1);//This produces data
        //System.out.println(vfname);//as does this StringProperty [value: what ever s1] 
    }

    public String getFName() {
        return vfname.get();
    }
    public void setFName(String s1) {   
        vfname.set(s1);
    }

    public String getLName() {
        return vlname.get();
    }
    public void setLName(String s2) {
        vlname.set(s2);
    }

    public String getPNum() {
        return vpnum.get();
    }
    public void setPNum(String s3) {
        vpnum.set(s3);
    }

    public String getEMail() {
        return vemail.get();
    }
    public void setEMail(String s4) {
        vemail.set(s4);
    }

}
FXML class
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.input.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="apCSV" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="1040.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="appCSVFile.CSVController">
    <children>
        <Pane fx:id="paneONE" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="1040.0"
            style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <MenuBar style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;">
                    <menus>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onLoad"
                                    text="Load">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="L"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#oneSave"
                                    text="Save">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="S"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onRemove"
                                    text="Remove">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="R"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClear"
                                    text="Clear">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="C"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Navigate">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onNext"
                                    text="Forward">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="F"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onPrevious"
                                    text="Previous">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="P"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onDir"
                                    text="Directions" />
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                    </menus>
                </MenuBar>
                <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="73.0"
                    text="First Name">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField fx:id="txfFName" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="70.0"
                    style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" />
                <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="370.0" layoutY="73.0"
                    text="Last Name">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField fx:id="txfLName" layoutX="470.0" layoutY="70.0"
                    prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="230.0" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" />
                <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="113.0"
                    text="Phone Number">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField fx:id="txfPNum" layoutX="179.0" layoutY="110.0"
                    prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="164.0" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;"
                    text="505-412-7650" />
                <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="405.0" layoutY="113.0"
                    text="E-Mail">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField fx:id="txfEMail" layoutX="470.0" layoutY="110.0"
                    prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="230.0" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" />
                <VBox fx:id="vbxDir" alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="150.0"
                    layoutY="163.0" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="190.0" visible="false">
                    <children>
                        <Button focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false"
                            onAction="#onClose" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" text="CLOSE" />
                        <TextArea focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="215.0"
                            prefWidth="190.0"
                            style="-fx-border-width: 2; -fx-border-color: blue; -fx-font-weight: bold;"
                            text="     Shortcut Directions&#10;&#10;Alt + L  to Load&#10;Alt + S  to Save&#10;&#10;Alt + R  to Remove&#10;Alt + C  to Clear&#10;&#10;Alt + F  Scroll Next&#10;Alt + P  Scroll Previous" />
                    </children>
                </VBox>
                <TableView fx:id="table" editable="true" layoutX="68.0"
                    layoutY="190.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="855.0">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="tblColFName" maxWidth="200.0"
                            minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="First Name" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="tblColLName" maxWidth="240.0"
                            minWidth="240.0" prefWidth="240.0" text="Last Name" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="tblColPNum" maxWidth="175.0"
                            minWidth="175.0" prefWidth="175.0" text="Phone Number" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="tblColEMail" maxWidth="240.0"
                            minWidth="240.0" prefWidth="240.0" text="Email Address" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
            </children>
        </Pane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: There are lots of errors in your code (too many to really fix in an answer to a single question); I think you haven't really understood how the `TableView` works. I recommend you look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm) (you can download [source code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/sample-apps/FXMLTableView.zip) for the complete example), and start from there.

Answer (score 0):

@James_Duh Your direction is good but as @James_D said a lot of errors. I have reworked your code and will offer a suggestion of looking at the Book Learn JavaFX 8 it is very complete. For a 6th grader you have neat code keep at it

```
Main Class
package appCSVFile;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class CSVMain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage pStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("csv.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,1040,650);
            pStage.setScene(scene);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            pStage.setResizable(false);
            pStage.setTitle("CSV File Demo");
            pStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Controller Class

package appCSVFile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

public class CSVController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private AnchorPane apCSV;
    @FXML private Pane paneONE;

    @FXML public TextField txfFName;
    @FXML public TextField txfLName;
    @FXML public TextField txfPNum;
    @FXML public TextField txfEMail;
    @FXML private VBox vbxDir;

    @FXML public TableView<Person> table;
    @FXML public TableColumn <Person,String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn <Person,String> lastNameColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn <Person,String> phoneNumberColumn;
    @FXML public TableColumn <Person,String> emailAddressColumn;

    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    public ArrayList<Contacts> list;
    private ListIterator<Contacts> LIT;
    private int i;

    public ObservableList<Person> data;

    @FXML
    private void onDir(ActionEvent e) {
        vbxDir.setVisible(true);
        vbxDir.toFront();
    }
    @FXML
    private void onClose(ActionEvent e) {
        vbxDir.setVisible(false);
    }

    @FXML//Load CSV Data
    private void onLoad(ActionEvent e)throws IOException {

        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();//Hold data for the table

        File fileInfo = new File("C:/A_CSV/People.csv");
        if(fileInfo.length()==0) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            alert.setHeaderText("");
            alert.setContentText("No Data in File at "+ fileInfo+"\n"+
            "Enter Data and Save");
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;  
        }

        fc.setTitle("Load Contacts Info");
        fc.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:/"));
        fc.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:/A_CSV"));
        fc.setInitialFileName("People.csv");
        File file = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (file == null) {
        return;
        }

        String correctFile = file.getName();
        if(!(correctFile.matches("People.csv"))){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            alert.setHeaderText("");
            alert.setContentText("The File at " + file + "\n\n"+
            "is NOT accociated with this application\n\n"+
            "Select the File at "+fileInfo);
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }

        Path dirP = Paths.get(String.valueOf(file));
        InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(dirP);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        list = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader);
        scan.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");

        while (scan.hasNext()){
           String fname = scan.next();
           String lname = scan.next();
           String pnum = scan.next();
           String email = scan.next();

           txfFName.setText(String.valueOf(fname));
           txfLName.setText(String.valueOf(lname));
           txfPNum.setText(String.valueOf(pnum));
           txfEMail.setText(String.valueOf(email));

           list.add(new Contacts(fname,lname,pnum,email));
           data.add(new Person(fname,lname,pnum,email));
           table.setItems(data);

           firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
           lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
           phoneNumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().phoneNumberProperty());
           emailAddressColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().emailAddressProperty());

        }
        scan.close();

        LIT = list.listIterator();                  
        if (LIT.hasNext()){          
            Contacts p = LIT.next();
            getContacts(p); 
        } 
    }

    @FXML//This code removes data from the ArrayList and RE-Writes to the
     //People.csv file the file is deleted first then rewritten
    private void onRemove(ActionEvent e)throws IOException{

    if(txfFName.getText().isEmpty()||txfLName.getText().isEmpty()||txfPNum.getText().isEmpty()||txfEMail.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("No Data Present to REMOVE\n"+
        "Click LOAD to Obtain Data");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return; 
    }

    list.get(i);
    list.remove(i);

    if(0 == list.size()){
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:/A_CSV", "People.csv");
    Files.delete(path);
        onClear(e);
        list.clear();
    return;
    }else if(i == list.size()){     
        i = i - 1;
    }
    Contacts p = list.get(i);
        getContacts(p);
        Contacts dat;

        for(int r = 0; r <list.size(); r++){
        dat = list.get(r);  
        }  
       Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:/A_CSV", "People.csv");
       Files.delete(path);

       File file = new File("C:/A_CSV/People.csv");
            if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.getPath(),true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);  
        Iterator<Contacts> LIT = list.iterator();
            while(LIT.hasNext()) {
                dat = LIT.next();
                String d = dat.toString();
                bufferWritter.write(d);
        }

        bufferWritter.close();
        onClear(e);
        //list.clear();//this is done by onClear(e)
        txfFName.requestFocus();
    }

    @FXML//Scroll forward through the ArrayList
    private void onNext(ActionEvent e) {

        if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("Load Data First");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return;
        }

        if (i == list.size()- 1) {
        i = 0;
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("Last Record in File");
        alert.showAndWait();
        i= list.size()-1;
        return;
        }else {
        i = i + 1;
        }
            Contacts p = list.get(i);
            getContacts(p); 
    }

    @FXML//Scroll backwards through the ArrayList
    private void onPrevious(ActionEvent e) {

        if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("Load Data First");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return;
        }

        if (i == 0) {
        i = list.size()-1;
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("First Record in File");
        alert.showAndWait();
        i=0;
        return;
        }else {
        i = i - 1 ;
        }
            Contacts p = list.get(i); 
            getContacts(p);
    }

    //Helper for Contacts Class
    private void getContacts(Contacts p){
        txfFName.setText("" + p.getFName());
        txfLName.setText("" + p.getLName());
        txfPNum.setText ("" + p.getPnum());
        txfEMail.setText("" + p.getEmail());    
    }

    @FXML
    private void oneSave(ActionEvent e) throws IOException{

    if(txfFName.getText().isEmpty() || txfLName.getText().isEmpty() || txfPNum.getText().isEmpty() || txfEMail.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("No DATA entered\n"+
        "ENTER new data and Alt + S to SAVE");
        alert.showAndWait();

        if(txfFName.getText().isEmpty()) {
            txfFName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(txfLName.getText().isEmpty()) {
            txfLName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(txfPNum.getText().isEmpty()) {
            txfPNum.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(txfEMail.getText().isEmpty()) {
            txfEMail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }   
    }

    String fname = txfFName.getText().trim();
    String lname = txfLName.getText().trim();
    String pnum = txfPNum.getText().trim();
    String email = txfEMail.getText().trim();
    String data = (fname + "," + lname + "," + pnum + "," + email + "," + '\r');

    File dirPath = new File("C:/A_CSV");
    dirPath.mkdirs();//Make the directory

    File file = new File(dirPath,"People.csv");
    if(!file.exists()){
       file.createNewFile();//Create and empty text file
    }

    Alert alert1 = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert1.setTitle("Confirm Save");
    alert1.setHeaderText("");
    alert1.setContentText("Select OK to Save Data");
    //Alert Do You Want to SAVE
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert1.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.getPath(),true);
        try (BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)) {
            bufferWritter.write(data);

        //Alert that you did SAVE too many Alerts!          
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Data Saved");
        alert.showAndWait();
        txfFName.setText("");
        txfLName.setText("");
        txfPNum.setText("");
        txfEMail.setText("");
        txfFName.requestFocus();
        table.getItems().clear();//Clears the table
    }

    } else {
        return;
        //if you did not save do we clear the entered data ?
        // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
    }
    }

    @FXML//Clear Fields and ArrayList
    private void onClear(ActionEvent e) {

    if(txfFName.getText().isEmpty()||txfLName.getText().isEmpty()||txfPNum.getText().isEmpty()||txfEMail.getText().isEmpty()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("No Data Present to CLEAR\n"+
        "Click LOAD to Obtain Data");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return; 
    }
    table.getItems().clear();
    i=0;
    list.clear();
    txfFName.setText("");
    txfLName.setText("");
    txfPNum.setText("");
    txfEMail.setText("");
    txfFName.requestFocus();
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        table.setPlaceholder(new Label("Select Help then Click Directions or Alt + L to Load Data"));

    }

    }

Contacts Class
package appCSVFile;

public class Contacts {

    private String FName;
    private String LName;
    private String PNum;
    private String EMail;

    //public Contacts(String pFname, String pLname, String pPnum, String pEmail) {
        //super();
        //this.FName = pFname;
        //this.LName = pLname;
        //this.PNum  = pPnum;
        //this.EMail = pEmail;
    //}
    public Contacts(String pFname,String pLname, String pPnum, String pEmail){
        FName = pFname;
        LName = pLname;
        PNum =  pPnum;
        EMail = pEmail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return FName + "," + 
           LName + "," +
           PNum  + "," +
           EMail + "," + '\r' ;
}
    public String toFile(){
        return FName + "," + LName + "," + PNum + "," + EMail + "," +'\r';
    }
    public String getFName(){
        return FName;
    }
    public String getLName(){
        return LName;
    }
    public String getPnum(){
        return PNum;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return EMail;
    }
}

Person Class
package appCSVFile;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {
    //This belongs to CSV Controller
    //===============================
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName", null);
    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", null);
    private final StringProperty phoneNumber = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "phoneNumber", null);
    private final StringProperty emailAddress = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "emailAddress", null);

    public Person() {
        this(null, null, null,null);
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber,String emailAddress) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
        this.phoneNumber.set(phoneNumber);
        this.emailAddress.set(emailAddress);
        }

    /* firstName Property */
    public final String getFirstName() {//1
    return firstName.get();
    }
    public final void setFirstName(String firstName) {//1
    firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
    }

    public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {//1
    return firstName;
    }

    public final String getLasttName() {//2
    return lastName.get();
    }
    public final void setLastName(String lastName) {//2
    lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
    }

    public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {//2
    return lastName;
    }

    public final String getPhoneNumber() {//3
    return phoneNumber.get();
    }
    public final void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {//3
    phoneNumberProperty().set(phoneNumber);
    }

    public final StringProperty phoneNumberProperty() {//3
    return phoneNumber;
    }

    public final String getEmailAddress() {
    return emailAddress.get();
    }
    public final void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    emailAddressProperty().set(emailAddress);
    }

    public final StringProperty emailAddressProperty() {
    return emailAddress;
    }
}
FXML file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.input.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="apCSV" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="1040.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="appCSVFile.CSVController">
    <children>
        <Pane fx:id="paneONE" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="1040.0"
            style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <MenuBar style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;">
                    <menus>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onLoad"
                                    text="Load">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="L"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#oneSave"
                                    text="Save">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="S"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onRemove"
                                    text="Remove">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="R"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClear"
                                    text="Clear">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="C"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Navigate">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onNext"
                                    text="Forward">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="F"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onPrevious"
                                    text="Previous">
                                    <accelerator>
                                        <KeyCodeCombination alt="ANY" code="P"
                                            control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                                    </accelerator>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onDir"
                                    text="Directions" />
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                    </menus>
                </MenuBar>
                <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="73.0"
                    text="First Name">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField fx:id="txfFName" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="70.0"
                    style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" />
                <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="370.0" layoutY="73.0"
                    text="Last Name">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField fx:id="txfLName" layoutX="470.0" layoutY="70.0"
                    prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="230.0" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" />
                <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="113.0"
                    text="Phone Number">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField fx:id="txfPNum" layoutX="179.0" layoutY="110.0"
                    prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="164.0" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;"
                    text="505-412-7650" />
                <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="405.0" layoutY="113.0"
                    text="E-Mail">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField fx:id="txfEMail" layoutX="470.0" layoutY="110.0"
                    prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="230.0" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" />
                <VBox fx:id="vbxDir" alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="150.0"
                    layoutY="163.0" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="190.0" visible="false">
                    <children>
                        <Button focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false"
                            onAction="#onClose" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" text="CLOSE" />
                        <TextArea focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="215.0"
                            prefWidth="190.0"
                            style="-fx-border-width: 2; -fx-border-color: blue; -fx-font-weight: bold;"
                            text="     Shortcut Directions&#10;&#10;Alt + L  to Load&#10;Alt + S  to Save&#10;&#10;Alt + R  to Remove&#10;Alt + C  to Clear&#10;&#10;Alt + F  Scroll Next&#10;Alt + P  Scroll Previous" />
                    </children>
                </VBox>
                <TableView fx:id="table" editable="true" layoutX="50.0"
                    layoutY="190.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="861.0">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" editable="false"
                            maxWidth="200.0" minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" resizable="false"
                            sortable="false" text="First Name" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameColumn" editable="false"
                            maxWidth="240.0" minWidth="240.0" prefWidth="240.0" resizable="false"
                            text="Last Name" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="phoneNumberColumn" editable="false"
                            maxWidth="175.0" minWidth="175.0" prefWidth="175.0" resizable="false"
                            sortable="false" text="Phone Number" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="emailAddressColumn" editable="false"
                            maxWidth="240.0" minWidth="240.0" prefWidth="240.0" resizable="false"
                            sortable="false" text="Email Address" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
            </children>
        </Pane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you explain how to make the data load when the application starts? I am not sure where to place the code. I tried the MainClass but that does not work. I would like to not use the file chooser. Your code worked great

Comment: Have you looked at these ? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

Comment: You will need a CellValueFactory to get the correct string from the CSV data, that is explained in that tutorial.